# Are song titles protected by copyrights?

Tags: copyright, music, branding

I have been working on a brand for a while, I have multiple designs and each design is based off of the logo, which is a clean styled text.

If the name of my brand was inspired/is an existing song title, is their title protected under a copyright?

Notes:

1. I'm in the USA
2. My brand makes no reference to the singer or song in general
3. My brand name is just the same as the song title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The US Copyright Office does not recognize copyright in titles: https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ34.pdf

Comment: Does that also extend to album 'titles' ?

Answer (score -1):

No, but you can protect them with a trademark.

Comment: It really depends on how the song title has been used. It won't always be eligible for a trademark.